# TSQL order by but first show these

Tags: t-sql, sql-order-by

I'm researching a dataset.
And I just wonder if there is a way to order like below in 1 query

```
Select * From MyTable where name ='international%' order by id
Select * From MyTable where name != 'international%' order by id
```

So first showing all international items, next by names who dont start with international.

My question is not about adding columns to make this work, or use multiple DB's, or a largerTSQL script to clone a DB into a new order.
I just wonder if anything after '**Where** or **order by**' can be tricked to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use expressions in the `ORDER BY`:

```
Select * From MyTable
order by
  CASE
    WHEN name like 'international%' THEN 0
    ELSE 1
  END,
  id
```

(From your narrative, it also sounded like you wanted `like`, not `=`, so I changed that too)

Comment: This is actually an excelent way of doing it, because its possible to add multiple Case statements, so one can add multiple first orders  (ea International, Europe, National, provincial, city, local)

Answer (score 0):

Another way (slightly cleaner and a tiny bit faster)

```
-- Sample Data
DECLARE @mytable TABLE (id INT IDENTITY, [name] VARCHAR(100));    
INSERT  @mytable([name])
VALUES('international something' ),('ACME'),('international waffles'),('ABC Co.');

-- solution
SELECT t.*
FROM @mytable AS t
ORDER BY -PATINDEX('international%', t.[name]);
```

Note too that you can add a persisted computed column for `-PATINDEX('international%', t.[name])` to speed things up.

Comment: works as well, but its not a solution after 'where'